# Reset ubuntu to its default state

Tags: 12.10, reset

I'd like to delete all files and programs on ubuntu 12.10 except the preinstalled ones (in one word, I want to reset the system to it's default state).

Is there any way to do this without reinstalling the OS?

Comment: Short of "reinstalling" there's no extremely easy method for completely wiping all files and data from your system and restoring to the original "cleanly installed" state.

Comment: Then it seems that I have to reinstall ubuntu. All right, I'll create a backup and try to make it. Thank you for your answer, I apreciate it!